# Riemann method for partial sum of $d(n)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How can I show that, for every $\epsilon>0$, $$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)=x\log x+(2\gamma-1)x+O(x^{1/2+\epsilon}),$$ where $\gamma$ is thge Euler-Mascheroni constant?

Comment: By performing a little googling about *Dirichlet hyperbola method*.

Comment: There is a nice exposition on Terence Tao's blog, too.

Comment: Thank you Jack, could you give me a specific link to find the problem in the blog?

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dirichlet-hyperbola-method/

Comment: A short proof is here: http://planetmath.org/dirichlethyperbolamethod